# Kafka change Offset from Latest to earliest

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a consumer with 'latest' offset. If I change to earliest, Does my consumer read the messages from starting offset (OR) does it continue from where latest offset left ? no change in consumer group name.

Answer (score 2):

If you've started the consumer already, and it has created a group (committed offsets), then `auto.offset.reset` value doesn't matter; it'll continue reading from the last committed offset.

If you want to reset the offsets for an existing group, you need to run `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` tool, or manually call `seek` methods on the consumer before it starts polling.

Comment: Assuming you are using spring-kafka (given it was originally tagged that way), you can have your listener extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` to get a number of utility methods for performing seeks on the assigned partitions. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek